# Trying to make a Bezier Curve on PyGame library

Tags: python, pygame, bezier, curve

I started messing around with PyGame lately, so i tried making a bezier curve, however, it turns out the curve doesn't end on the points i would like to. Heres the code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import numpy as np

pygame.init()

x = 1200
y = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((x,y))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    p0 = 30,30
    p1 = 60,15
    p2 = 30,90
    t = 0
    for i in np.arange(0,1,0.001):
            px = p0[0]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*p1[0] + p2[0]*t**2
            py = p0[1]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*p1[1] + p2[1]*t**2
            t = t + 0.01        
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0), (px,py,1,1))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your formula correctly, `t` should take on values from 0 through 1 to trace out the entire curve.  But you're actually giving it values from 0 to 10...  What was the point of the `for i` loop if you're not going to use `i` for anything?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, i was dumb for not using the ```i```. But after setting it for going 0 to 1, it still doesn't start on the coordinate i setted it to.

Comment: The second problem is because you copied the formula incorrectly: it should be `2*(1-t)*t*p1[0]` as the middle term.

Comment: Why is your for loop for `i` instead of for `t`? That said, `arange` (and `range`) are `[start, end)`, not `[start, end]` so you're never going to get the point for `t=1`. You probably want something like `for t in [v/steps for v in range(0,steps+1)]: ...`

Answer (score 3):

the formula is wrong. `*t` is missing in the middle term:

<s>`px = p0[0]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*p1[0] + p2[0]*t**2`</s>
<s>`py = p0[1]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*p1[1] + p2[1]*t**2`</s>

```py
px = p0[0]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*t*p1[0] + p2[0]*t**2
py = p0[1]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*t*p1[1] + p2[1]*t**2
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import numpy as np

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
    
    p0 = 30,30
    #p1 = 60,15
    p1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    p2 = 30,190
    
    screen.fill(0)
    for p in [p0, p1, p2]:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), p, 5)
    for t in np.arange(0, 1, 0.01):
        px = p0[0]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*t*p1[0] + p2[0]*t**2
        py = p0[1]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*t*p1[1] + p2[1]*t**2       
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (px, py, 1, 1))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the algorithm a tiny bit to draw a continuous line instead of circles

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import numpy as np

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
    
    p0 = 30,30
    #p1 = 60,15
    p1 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    p2 = 30,190
    
    lastPoint = None
    screen.fill(0)
    for p in [p0, p1, p2]:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), p, 5)
    for t in np.arange(0, 1, 0.01):
        point = (p0[0]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*t*p1[0] + p2[0]*t**2, p0[1]*(1-t)**2 + 2*(1-t)*t*p1[1] + p2[1]*t**2)
        if lastPoint is not None:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 0), lastPoint, point, 1)
        lastPoint = point       

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```